# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect not stopping redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am developing a chrome extension, and in part of the extension I need to detect redirection and ask the user whether he/she wishes to proceed. I tried doing this using chrome's webRequest API, but it doesn't seem to work properly, even though I'm sure my syntax is right. Here is the relevant code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function (details) {
    if(details.frameId == 0){
        if (confirm("This link is a redirect. Do you want to continue?")){
            /* do nothing and let them redirect */
        }
        else {
            /* stop the redirect from happening */
            return {cancel: true};
        }
    }
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

Why isn't the method blocking properly?

Comment: alert/confirm/prompt are to be [modernized](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wtV5rmLhbf1OZkbg7crtCt6h1mMtig_ctTQt3BLLEIU/edit) in order not to block the js engine and the browser. Maybe they already implemented it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [official guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRedirect), you're not allowed to cancel the redirect

> onBeforeRedirect
>
> Fires when a redirect is about to be executed. A redirection can be triggered by an HTTP response code or by an extension. This event is informational and handled asynchronously. **It does not allow you to modify or cancel the request.**

Answer (score 2):

Haibara is perfectly correct in that `onBeforeRedirect` is purely informational, but let me add to that.

`onBeforeRequest` and `onBeforeSendHeaders` are the only events that can - i.e. *cancelling* is only possible before the request is actually made. It's a question of defining "cancel", since the request is already out.

---

Note that you can use `onHeadersReceived` for your purpose - headers provided in that event are the ones used to redirect the request, and you can override it by redirecting (which is allowed at that point) to your own extension page.

---

However, I must also say that you may be chasing the wrong suspect here. As far as I understand `webRequest`, this will only catch [HTTP 3** redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx); any other redirect method, such as changing `window.location`, will mean that this particular *network* request succeeds, and then generates a subsequent navigation, which is transparent to `webRequest`.

All the while the HTTP 3** redirects are most often used for benign purposes of rewriting http to https or modifying the URL to a canonical one.